# How to clear a column in gspread?

Tags: python, gspread

I am using gspread in a python script and I have been trying to find a quick way of clearing a column in a given sheet.

**Q:** How can I clear the columns with gspread?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=update_cells#gspread.models.Worksheet.update_cells).

You can only clear entire rows or multiple cells.

So, for a column you will need to do something like this :

```
worksheet = sheet.get_worksheet(0)

# Select a range (row by row)
cell_list = worksheet.range("N2:P2")
cell_list.extend(worksheet.range("N3:P3"))
cell_list.extend(worksheet.range("N4:P4"))
cell_list.extend(worksheet.range("N5:P5"))
cell_list.extend(worksheet.range("N6:P6"))

# Set the value
for cell in cell_list:
    cell.value = ''

# Update in batch
worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is from [gspread](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.1.1/user-guide.html#clear-a-worksheet) document and it works for me.
To clear a column 'A' in a google sheet from all its contain

```
worksheet.batch_clear(['A:A'])
```

I hope this is useful for someone

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Clear method does not exist. You should loop through the data and

```
update_cell(row, col, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

In latest version of `gspread` you have the following method [values_cldar](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.1.1/api.html#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.values_clear) it takes a range as argument and will clear this range in a single HTTP request.

It should look like:

```
spsh = client.open("my sheet")
spsh.values_clear("A1:P4")
```

Comment: Did not notice but question is as old as 2016. We'll never get an response from question owner.